# Generating Code Metrics file from command line gives no results

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I'm trying to generate Code Metrics data for my project that contains multiple modules. When I generate Code Metrics analysis in Visual Studio 2019 I get valid results for the project.
I have based my command line generation on the Microsoft document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-generate-code-metrics-data?view=vs-2019
I have the following command line script running as a post build event:

```
msbuild SIMSMobile.sln /t:Metrics /p:MetricsOutputFile="MetricsOutput.xml" /p:Configuration="Debugging Release"
```

This worked just over a month ago giving valid results in an xml file as described in the Microsoft document.
Recently I've discovered my results are no longer valid. The file generated is as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeMetricsReport Version="1.0">
  <Targets>
    <Target Name="SIMSMobileView.csproj">
      <Assembly Name="SIMSMobileView, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
        <Metrics>
          <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
          <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="0" />
          <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="0" />
          <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="0" />
          <Metric Name="SourceLines" Value="0" />
          <Metric Name="ExecutableLines" Value="0" />
        </Metrics>
      </Assembly>
    </Target>
  </Targets>
</CodeMetricsReport>
```

I don't understand how this has happened. I haven't changed my script or anything.
I've tried checking out a commit that I know was working at the time, but running my command line metrics generation gives the same empty xml file as above.

I've tried using the Metrics.exe method to generate my output metrics file as explained in the Microsoft document and that gives me the same empty file as above.
I've updated the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers Nuget Package to the latest stable version and that did nothing.
Running Code Metrics on my solution within VS 2019 gives me meaningful results.
Why can't I get the same results from using the command line and generating an output file?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar behavior on a Windows Server.
After I set the environment variable `MSBuildSDKsPath`, the Metrics.exe generates the correct metrics file again.

```
set MSBuildSDKsPath=C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\Sdks
```

I still don't know exactly why it worked before, but I will let you know when I find the exact root cause.

Comment: I've tried setting the environment variable to the path on my system which is 
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.202\Sdks but this hasn't changed my output. Still getting the output file as shown in the original post.

Comment: @user1845860 I am sorry that it does not work for you. I found the hint [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/analyze-calculate-code-metrics-does-not-work-anymo/526995#T-N1150820). Maybe you can find information there to find your cause.

Comment: its strange. When I set MSBuildSDKsPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.111\Sdks" I got the same output. But when I set MSBuildSDKsPath=C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.425\Sdks, everything works

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the `dotnet`CLI, which calls msbuild internally:

```
dotnet msbuild SIMSMobile.sln /t:Metrics /p:MetricsOutputFile="MetricsOutput.xml" /p:Configuration="Debugging Release"
```